Injective Functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to Finite Subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with Completely Multiplicative Cardinalities?
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}.$ Can we find all functions $f : \mathbb{N}\to \mathcal{F}$ satisfying following properties:

$f$ is injective
Cardinality of $f$ is completely multiplicative.
i.e., $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\vert f(mn)\vert=\vert f(m)\vert\vert f(n)\vert$.

A trivial example is the initial segment function: $f(n)=\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}.$
Also, there are multiple near misses, such as

$f(n)=\text{ set of divisors of $n$}$
$f(n)=\text{ set of integers that are coprime to $n$ and less than or equal $n$}$

These functions are injective, but multiplicative only when $\gcd(m, n)=1.$
I'm wondering whether there are other interesting examples of functions satisfying both of these conditions. It would be very nice if there is a characterization of all functions with these properties.

A simpler example is just $f(n)={n}$.

Since your multiplicativity test is purely based on cardinality, you can make many more functions of your type just by applying any cardinality preserving bijection on the collection of sets.  That's a lot of functions.
